# MySQL query involving complicated summing function

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know how to put my requirement in words but let me explain it with a table and output that I desire

The table looks like this

```
Package      LanguageUsed  UnitsSold
lmn          basic           43
xyz          pascal          20
abc          basic           50
cba          c               20
```

Output I want is

```
LanguageUsed   UnitsSold
basic             93                43+50
pascal            20                20+ nothing
c                 20                20+ nothing
```

I need to display **number of** packages sold in **each language**

How can I do this in MySQL?

Comment: Using `GROUP BY` and `SUM`. It is quite easy, you should try it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to display number of packages sold in each language

You can do:

```
SELECT languageUsed, SUM(UnitsSold)
FROM yourTABLE
GROUP BY languageUsed
```

Comment: what's about __"+nothing"__ desired in output?

Comment: That's just an explanation of what they desire. IMO that's just an elaboration of the fact that those rows are not being repeated. `I need to display number of packages sold in each language`

Comment: I tried your query but I get two rows with languagedeveloped basic 43 and basic 50

Comment: Sorry I grouped on the wrong column name. Try the updated one

Comment: It is not complicated for you. I don't know the use of group by that's why I said the word complicated